# How to get scheduled build\release data using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, schedule

Would like to get what is the next expected Build/Release and get the information using API then project it some form of Dashboard (With the collected information) rather than checking from Azure DevOps > Pipelines > Builds option.

Scheduler has been enabled for both Build & Release pipelines and it is getting triggered successfully as well. I'm able to collect build/release information using REST API, however i can get the info of processed/completed builds/releases.

Based on the requirement, i just want to get the next scheduled build/release details (any info about them is fine) as I have enabled scheduler for them.

If Scheduler just helps in triggering the pipelines, is there any way we can retrieve that information programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get scheduled build\release data using REST API

You could use Rest API to [Get a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the build schedule information:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

For example, I use following Powershell scripts to get the build schedule information:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<MyOrganization>/<MyProject>/_apis/build/definitions/55?api-version=5.1"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$scheduledstartHours= $buildPipeline.triggers.schedules.startHours
$scheduledstartMinutes= $buildPipeline.triggers.schedules.startMinutes
$scheduledNumber= $buildPipeline.triggers.schedules.daysToBuild
$scheduledJobId= $buildPipeline.triggers.schedules.scheduleJobId

Write-Host This is start Hours: $scheduledstartHours
Write-Host This is start Minutes: $scheduledstartMinutes
Write-Host This is scheduled Number: $scheduledNumber
Write-Host This is scheduled Job Id: $scheduledJobId
```

As the test result:

[image]

Note:

- When to build is indicated by **buildNnumber** when you select more
  than 1 day in the schedule, but MS does not provide a comparison table.
- When you use above scripts, you need go to the `Agent Phase` and select
  `Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token`. See [Use the OAuth token to
  access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)

For the release schedule information, you could use the [Get a Release Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) as same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @praveenkrish, We could get this information before this build gets triggered! Because those info are comes from the definition settings not the build, so, you just need set the scheduled, then you can get this info. BTW, above test result are obtained before the build trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. And, is there anyway we can get this information before this build gets triggered, in a pro-active way ? Or this information will be available once after the scheduled build has ran ? 
I just want to get the upcoming build details. Is that can be achievable ? Please let me know your suggestion. Thanks.